# Databricks writing data to MapD: Connection failed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, etl

When I try to write a simple table (simpleTable) to `MapD`, I get the following error:

`java.sql.SQLException: Connection failed - org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException:` `Connection refused (Connection refused)`

Here is my code:

```
%python
simpleTable.write.format("jdbc").option("url", 
"jdbc:mapd:localhost:8000:mapd:http").option("driver", 
JDBC_DRIVER).option("dbtable", "venues").option("user", "mapd").option("password", "<PasswordHere>").save()
```

Comment: Is it because the library isn't loaded, or is this an issue on the MapD side? If there are any geniuses please show yourselves

Comment: Connection refused means that it was able to contact but unable to communicate. Without more of the exception this would be really hard to determine. But my guess would be either the port/protocol/ or authentication is wrong.